# What are the differences between to create a "classic" class in javascript and JSON notation?

Tags: javascript, json, class

In Javascript there are several ways to create a class. But I have some doubts between these two ways:

```
function MyClass(){

    this.myFun = function(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and

```
var MyClass = {

    myFun: function(){
        // do stuff  
    }
}
```

The only difference is that the second way I can't to use a `new` operator? So the Json notation allows me to create a static class or singleton class, right?

Comment: Typically yes, the object notation is used for singletons and the constructor for prototype chains but in ES5 you have `Object.create` making objects more extendable.

Comment: Best not to call that syntax "Json", because although "JSON" stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" the term "JSON" is applied to a _string_ representation of data usually used for data interchange. Used within actual JS code, what you've got is an "object literal" or what MDN calls an "object initialiser". (The JSON syntax is a subset of object literal syntax, and can't for example contain funcdtions.)

Comment: You're right. I always use the term incorrectly :(

Answer (score 3):

A few minor corrections. In JS these is only class **simulation** - the language lacks a formalised notion of actual classes. And your JSON notation is actually a JS object - that would be invalid JSON as you currently have it.

You do not have to use an object to simulate the singleton pattern. You can do this with constructors like so:

```
function Animal() {
    if (Animal.instance) return Animal.instance;
    Animal.instance = this;
    /* constructor code here */
}
var animal_a = new Animal(); //constructor runs
var animal_b = new Animal(); //singleton instance returns
console.log(animal_a === animal_b); //true
```

Also, with your first approach, note it is better to put reusable, inheritable code on the prototype rather than declaring separately for each instance. This is faster, and also more sensible - the prototype is the place for this.

```
function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype.method = function() {}
```

This also avoids the problem of distinguishing between own and inherited properties, which, in your code, could not be done because you're declaring methods separately on each instance.

[**EDIT** - in response to the OP's question about private members]

Private members are implemented as local variables/functions, which means they are inaccessible outside the current closure.

```
function Animal() {
    var private_var = 'foo';
    function private_method = function() { alert('bar'); };
}
```

Public methods may (if you choose) be able to get or set them - but in order that they themselves have access to these private members, they would have to be declared inside the constructor, not separately, outside it.

```
function Animal() {
    var private_var = 'foo';
    function private_method = function() { alert('bar'); };
    if (!Animal.prototype.public_method)
        Animal.prototype.public_method = function() {
            alert(private_var);
        };
}
var dog = new Animal();
dog.public_method(); //'foo'
```

Comment: I know and understand what you are saying, I just want to help the asker and future readers out with something that they CAN understand. In MY opinion explaining apples with pears will never render an understanding as to why things work the way they do in the prototypal language that is JavaScript/ECMA Script. You explain: 'the language lacks a formalised notion of actual classes', to me that is like saying: a bicycle lacks a muffler (duh..). Think of where the world would be now if over the last decade nobody explained javascript with classes..

Comment: Thanks to answer. I knew this way. But the problem that way is the impossibility to create a truly private method and property. So in every project I must choose if I prefer the performance or the private method.

Comment: JS implements private members via closures. I can edit if interested if you don't know this already.

Answer (score 3):

The code you showed doesn't create *classes*. The notion of `class` is unknown to javascript, it uses [prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). Now as to your code. The first piece of code represents a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). From it, you can derive *instances* - javascript objects with shared properties -, using the keyword `new`.

```
function MyConstructor(name){
  this.name = name || 'no name yet';
  this.myFun = function(){
     alert(this.name);
  }
}
var instanceA = new MyConstructor('Webman')
   ,instanceB = new MyConstructor;
instanceA.myFun(); //=> 'Webman'
instanceB.myFun(); //=> 'no name yet'
```

The second piece of code creates a single javascript object. It uses an [object literal](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2138-how-to-use-object-literals-in-javascript/) notation.

```
var mySingleObject = {
    myFun: function(){
        alert('I am single');
    }
};
mySingleObject.myFun(); //=> 'I am single'
```

The Mozilla Developer Network has a [nice page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model), where things are explained in more detail.

Creating an object using an object literal, everything is public. Using a constructor, it is possible to have private variables, using javascripts [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) mechanism:

```
function MyConstructor(name){
   var namestring = 'the name property of this instance is: '+ 
                     (name || 'not set'); 
   this.myFun = function(){
     alert(namestring);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no classes in javascript, javascript is a prototypal language.
There is no way to explain this faster than watching: [Crockford on JavaScript - Chapter 2: And Then There Was JavaScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO1Wnu-xKoY) for a simple CORRECT explanation by the father of json (amongst other things).

Good Luck!!